# The antiforgery token could not be decrypted - Same app multiple times on the same server - Virtual Directories

Tags: c#, asp.net, antiforgerytoken, x-xsrf-token

I have published the same app to the same server but on different virtual directories.

https://server.com/test
https://server.com/prod

I get the error from the title, I suppose ASP.NET MVC "sees" them as the same website (server.com)

For sure there must be a setup or a configuration to make them work together, but couldn't find anything online.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET do you use?

Comment: Latest (MVC 5.2) - .NET 6

Answer (score 1):

> I suppose ASP.NET MVC "sees" them as the same website (server.com).

- No, they are considered as different apps in your webserver.

The problem is about the signing/encryption of the anti-forgery tokens that is governed by the keys held in the  section of your web config. if you don't explicitly define them the asp.net will generates them automatically of course they will be unique and different on your two virtual directories and they will be cached on your browser, then when you switch requsts between your two instance you got this error.

the solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38462232/6770600).

more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff649308(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#paght000007_webfarmdeploymentconsiderations).

Comment: I tried to put two different machine keys in web.configs but it didn't solve my issue

Comment: It would make more sense to have the SAME machine key. Tried, but still it doesn't work :(

Comment: Fixed it! As I am using a cookie to send the token, I only had to set a different path for the cookie.

Comment: The cookie workaround is good for your scenario. but if you had a serverless app that doesn't seem good.
happy it hepled you. so please vote up my answer :)  @CătălinRădoi